# cannot access a model field from filter queryset result

Tags: python, django

I have a model like this:

```
class MeetingMember(models.Model):
    CHOICES = (
        ("A", "Accepted"),
        ("R", "Rejected"), 
    )

    status = models.CharField(max_length=9,choices=CHOICES,default=None)
    meeting = models.ForeignKey(Meeting, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="members2")
    user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="memberships")
```

and in my views.py I have this code:

```
 if get_user_model().objects.get(email=email):
            
     member = MeetingMember.objects.filter(meeting=meeting).filter(user__email=email)
            
     if len(member)==0:
         print(member.user)
         print('not joined yet')
     elif member.status=="A":
         print('accepted')
     else:
         print('rejected') 
          
else:
     print('not found')
```

but I get this error:

```
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'user'
```

Any suggestion on how to fix it?

Note: `MeetingMember` model is used in my other model files/field like this:

```
joined_members = models.ManyToManyField(get_user_model(), blank=True, through='MeetingMember')
```

Comment: BTW, when asking a question, you should fix indentation and punctuation and show the full error message, including the traceback.

Comment: (Welcome to stack**overflow**.) Please sort out whether in your `Note:` it should read *fields*, *files* or something else - *models*? The rationale for removing "aTdHvAaNnKcSe" is [no signature, taglines, or greetings](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) - in accordance with [This site is all about getting answers […\] There's no chit-chat](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filter()` returns a queryset, not a `MeetingMember` instance. Here are two alternative ways in which you could fix this:

```
member = MeetingMember.objects.get(meeting=meeting, user__email=email)
member = MeetingMember.objects.filter(meeting=meeting, user__email=email).first()
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Antonis's answer - you can also use `values` to get a list of users like so:

```
member = MeetingMember.objects.filter(...).values('user')
```